# Pandas swap multiple index levels at once

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Is there a way to swap multiple levels of a multiIndex dataframe at once?

I basically need to roll the position of my multiIndex such that I go from:

```
myIndexLevels= (0 ,1 ,2)
```

to:

```
myNewIndexLevels= (1 ,2, 0)
```

I know I can use swaplevel twice but I am quite sure there is a better way.

This is my solution as of now:

```
df.index.swaplevel(0,1).swaplevel(1,2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.reorder_levels.html):

```
df.index = df.index.reorder_levels((1,2,0))
```

Comment: Thanks, I suspected there was a function somewhere out there =)